# Which event is trigger when one window is hover on another window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have very strange requirement like there are two browser window .

i want to close second window when i dragged this window on first window.

**first Is this possible ?**

**Second If yes then On which event ?**

So i can do my desire work at that event.

Right now i have written this code

```
$(document).on('mouseover', function () {
 console.log('done'); 
});
```

SO i can get this event when i dargged another window on first window but this event also not happening because at the drag time dragged window active, this window is not active.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you considered the ux part of this ?

Comment: no i just  want close second window when dragged on first window. 
and window are not JavaScript modal box these are browser window.

Comment: are both windows in your control?

Comment: What does "drag a window on other window" mean?!

Comment: @madalinivascu  they are both child window opened by parent window.

Comment: and why downvote  i am just asking a question can someone explain why downvote ?

Comment: you can close the parent window when the child window is open

Comment: yes that i now but my requirement is between two child window 
 one one child window dragged to another child window then firstone is closed

Comment: Constantly check their dimension and position?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat How can you please explain

Comment: @Riturajratan Can you explain or add the code for child window.

Comment: @Jai i have written  `$(document).on('mouseover', function () {
        console.log('done');
    });`  so when i dragged another window so i can get this event but is not happening.

Comment: @Riturajratan i asked how you created child window?

Comment: @Jai by `window.open `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check both windows' dimension and position. The snippet below will not work here as StackOverflow blocks pop up windows, so try it somewhere else.

```js
var a;
var b;

function openA(){
    a = window.open("","w1","width=250,height=150,top=0");
    a.document.title = "A";
}

function openB(){
    b = window.open("","w2","width=250,height=150,top=200,left=400");
    b.document.title = "B";
}

setInterval(function(){
    // If both window is not closed
    if (a && !a.closed && b && !b.closed){
        // If both window overlaps
        if (
            a.screenX + a.outerWidth > b.screenX &&
            a.screenX < b.screenX + b.outerWidth &&
            a.screenY + a.outerHeight > b.screenY &&
            a.screenY < b.screenY + b.outerWidth
        ){
            b.close();
        }
    }
},1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="openA()">Open window A</button>
<button onclick="openB()">Open window B</button>
```

Comment: hey this works :)  
one more question if i want child window close when i dragged to it parent window.

like in your case two child window dragged to each other one window closed now i want to close child window when dragged to parent window  is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, you need to compare with the parent `screenX` and `outerWidth`. Change `a` to the current window and `b` remains as the child

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared any code about child windows and as per comments i can suggest you this:

1. `var cwin = window.open()` creates a child window.
2. Now you can use to get the **X** position of your window.
3. You can use `setInterval()` to check the position of that window.
4. Then you can check if the **X** position is in between the width of parent window.
5. Here you can trigger `$(cwin.parent.document).trigger('mouseover')` close it by `cwin.close();`

Comment: thanks i got it by window.screenX  i will get X position

Comment: and on that case when window are not parent child they are in same level like one child window and another one also child window then how will close one child window when it dragged to first child window.